C# - How to get the current row index of a DataGridView from a different Form?
I currently have two forms--my main form, Form1, which has a DataGridView who's data source is a BindingList. Form2 is accessed via a button press, and is filled with textboxes populated with data from said BindingLists. For example, the code for that (in Form2) looks like the following:
Textbox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text",SomeClass.SomeBindingList[0], "Field2"));
Textbox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", SomeClass.SomeBindingList[0], "Field2"));

This will populate Textbox1 and Textbox2 with stuff from index 0 of the BindingList. Now, I obviously want SomeClass.SomeBindingList[0] to use, instead of 0, the currently selected row number of the DataGridView in Form1.
In order to achieve this, I wrote the following code in Form2:
Form1 firstform = new Form1();
int testIndex = firstform.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

However, when I run the program, I get the error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: testIndex

When assigning dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index to an integer in Form1, I have no issue returning the correct value. I've even tried passing it FROM Form1 to a public int in Form2 but the same issue happens.
Basically what I want to know is if what I'm trying to achieve is possible, and how. Thanks!

Does this answer your question? Reference the Form in a separate class

Consider this. If I have a notebook and you want to know what is written on the first page, would getting a new notebook of the same type and looking at its first page be of any use to you? Of course not, so why are you doing basically the same thing here and expecting a different result? You need to reference the same form object that you're looking at on screen, because that's the one with the data.

The first thing to do is to decide whether you're going to use the default instance or not. If you show the default instance in the first place, you can use the default instance elsewhere to access the same form object. If you don't, you need to need to maintain a reference to the object you created and displayed. Start by reading this to learn about default instances.

try this
Form1.cs
private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
       
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(this, selectedIndex);
        form2.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a row first.");
    }
}

Form2.cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form1;
    private int _selectedIndex;

    public Form2(Form1 form1, int selectedIndex)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form1 = form1;
        _selectedIndex = selectedIndex;

        if (_selectedIndex >= 0 && _selectedIndex < SomeClass.SomeBindingList.Count)
        {
            Textbox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", SomeClass.SomeBindingList[_selectedIndex], "Field1"));
            Textbox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", SomeClass.SomeBindingList[_selectedIndex], "Field2"));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid row selected.");
        }
    }
}


thank you!!! This got me the result I was looking for!!
